# Publishing NPM package with np throws error with exit code 128 (Gatsby & rollup)

Tags: node.js, npm, publish, gatsby, rollupjs

I've had no problems *manually* publishing my scoped package to the NPM registry however I found the **np** module could be used to ensure no steps were skipped in the process.

I've configured only a couple options in my package.json as the defaults are otherwise sensible for me. (This is the package.json for the npm package itself)

```
{
  "name": "@scope/package",
  "version": "0.0.6",
  "description": "blah",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run release",
    "release": "npm run build:dev && npm run build:prod",
    "build:prod": "NODE_ENV=production rollup -c",
    "build:dev": "NODE_ENV=development rollup -c",
    "test": "echo \"No tests specified\""
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "http://blah/blah/blah"
  },
  "author": "blah",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "np": {                    <----
    "yarn": false,           <----
  },                         <----
  "publishConfig": {         <----
    "access": "public"       <----
  }                          <----
}
```

Unfortunately when I run np I receive the error:

*Command failed with exit code 128 (Unknown system error -128): git log --format=%s %h **commit sha** **commit sha**..HEAD*

The first **commit sha** is the initial commit from Gatsby.

If you've used Gatsby you may have seen it:

*Initial commit from gatsby: (https://github.com/gastbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world.git)*

For context: I'm creating a component library where the parent dir is setup using GatsbyJS so that I can use it for the demo site while the child dirs under src/packages will be the individual components that will be published to the npm registry. So the demo site is bundled with Gatsby while the packages are bundled using rollup.

Why am I receiving this -128 error code and how do I fix it?